# Validation failed, or the endpoint has been spammed. {Github's API}

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, github-api

I'm using Github's search API in Android App through retrofit
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=user

The API Service file states as :

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("search/users")
    suspend fun getUsers(@Query ("q") searchQuery: String)
    : UserResponse
}
```

Meanwhile, the data class is :

```
data class UserResponse(
    val total_count: Int,
    val incomplete_results: Boolean,
    val items: MutableList<Item>
){
    data class Item( val avatar_url: String,
                     val events_url: String,
                     val followers_url: String,
                     val following_url: String,
                     val gists_url: String,
                     val gravatar_id: String,
                     val html_url: String,
                     val id: Int,
                     val login: String,
                     val node_id: String,
                     val organizations_url: String,
                     val received_events_url: String,
                     val repos_url: String,
                     val site_admin: Boolean,
                     val starred_url: String,
                     val subscriptions_url: String,
                     val type: String,
                     val url: String)
}
```

But, I'm having an error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
> Process: com.example.github, PID: 3542
> retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 422

I tried change @Query param but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Class1 (

  @SerializedName("total_count") 
  var totalCount: Int? = null,
  @SerializedName("incomplete_results") 
  var incompleteResults : Boolean?= null,
  @SerializedName("items") var items: ArrayList<Items> = arrayListOf()

)


data class Items (

  @SerializedName("login") 
  var login: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("id")
  var id: Int? = null,
  @SerializedName("node_id") 
  var nodeId: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("avatar_url") 
  var avatarUrl: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("gravatar_id") 
  var gravatarId: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("url") 
  var url: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("html_url") 
  var htmlUrl: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("followers_url") 
  var followersUrl : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("following_url") 
  var followingUrl : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("gists_url") 
  var gistsUrl : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("starred_url") 
  var starredUrl: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("subscriptions_url") 
  var subscriptionsUrl  : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("organizations_url") 
  var organizationsUrl  : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("repos_url") 
  var reposUrl: String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("events_url") 
  var eventsUrl : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("received_events_url" ) 
  var receivedEventsUrl : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("type") 
  var type : String?  = null,
  @SerializedName("site_admin") 
  var siteAdmin : Boolean? = null,
  @SerializedName("score") 
  var score: Int?     = null

)
```